# How to redirect output of a command to a file when the command will prompt user inputs?

Tags: linux, bash, redirection, prompt

I have a command which will prompt user for some inputs and then output the result to the terminal. I typed the command like below to redirect the output to a file:

```
$the_command > abc.txt
```

But it doesn't work. The problem is there's no prompt, those prompt questions' text is output to the abc.txt not the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command works and properly redirects the output to the file `abc.txt`.
The question is **how is your script asking the input data** and how are you running the script?
Let we see with two examples:

```
# Script_1.sh                                     # 1
echo Please, enter your firstname and lastname    # 2
read FN LN                                        # 3
echo "Hi! $LN, $FN !"                             # 4
```

and

```
# Script_2.sh                                     # 5
read -p "Enter a comment " CM                     # 6
echo  "You said $CM"                              # 7
```

If you run `/bin/bash Script1.sh > abc.txt` you will not see the question "Please enter..." on your tty. If you will give the expected input from keyboard you will find the output of line #2 and #4 in your `abc.txt` file.

If you run `/bin/bash Script2.sh > abc.txt` you will see the question "Enter a comment ", but you will find in the `abc.txt` file only the output of the line #7.

Note: if you run the Script2,sh in a subshell

```
(bash Script2.sh 2>&1)> abc.txt
```

you will not see any output on tty and you will find all in the `abc.txt` file.
If you run it with

```
bash Script2.sh 2>ccc.txt 1>ddd.txt`
```

you will find the Standard output (line #7) in `ddd.txt` and the standard error (line #6) in`ccc.txt`.

---

If you want **to redirect only part of your command output** you have to modify your script.
One of the way to do it, is to create a function in which to move the part of the script that will generate the interesting output (see below). Then you can call this function from the *main part* of your script (where it was originally the code that you moved into the function) redirecting only that output to the log file:

```
 Part_To_Redirect(){
     : # all that you want
 }

 # ... Main part of the script
 # point where it was the part that generates the output
 Part_to_Redirect "$@" > abc.txt   # this to store only that part in the file
 # Part_to_Redirect "$@" >> abc.txt  # this to append that part in the file
 # ...
```

---

You should even find useful [`tee`](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html) that

> redirects the output to multiple files, **copies standard input to standard output** and also to any files given as arguments.

```
 the_command  | tee abc.txt       # To redirect Standard output
 or 
 the_command 2>&1 | tee abc.txt   # To redirect err in out and both in the file
```

In this case you will have the normal outputs of your command on the tty, but at the same time you will save a copy in the log file `abc.txt`. It should be cosy in your case if you use `read -p` as in the script2 the invocation `the_command | tee abc.txt`.

**Notes and references:**

Adding `"$@"` you can [pass all the argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine) of your script to the function.

You may find interesting to read more about bashredirection from many sources on internet.

- As suggested by [Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott) in his comment there is a [wiki answer of Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/66388): a good starting point.
- A must the `man bash` or [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).
- I found useful the redirection chapter of [bash-hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) where you can find links to [obsolete uses](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) too.
- You can refer to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), chapter 20 too.

Comment: I believe that [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408) is a better reference.

Comment: @Scott, precious as usual. There are so many sources on internet that nowadays it is difficult to select just one that fit _your_ needs, especially when you do not know the person (I mean the OP).

Comment: Well, the point is that I pointed you to ***our*** reference.  Also, I needed only to glance at your two to find inaccuracies and sloppy writing.  ("precious as usual"?)

Comment: @Scott: what didn't you like _precious_ or _usual_? We meet here [2 times in few days](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194898/66388) and both your comments helped me to do a better answer... and this made you, without any offence,  _"precious as usual"_. :-)

Comment: OK; "precious" struck me as being snide, but I guess that's a tertiary meaning.

Answer (score 3):

By default, only `STDOUT` is redirected and/or piped. What you want is to leave `STDOUT` alone, and have whatever is passed via `STDIN` redirected.

If editing `the_command` is an option, you could make sure that the question is output to `STDERR` instead (that should dump it to screen regardless of any redirects), and then have it echo whatever the user types back to screen via `STDOUT`.

Comment: _`STDERR` should dump it to screen regardless of any redirects_ No. If you redirect `2>xyz`, stderr is redirected as well. But a program can open and use `/dev/tty` which uses the controlling terminal regardless of any redirections.

Comment: @glglgl I've seen a couple of programs that insisted on working with `/dev/tty/` directly, and they were pretty annoying. They don't take input `STDIN`, they continue to pollute your terminal, and they're very surprised when they happen to run without a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There are usually 2 important output pipes: `STDOUT` (for regular output) and `STDERR` (for error messages).

The problem here is, that the "regular" output of the command and the text of the prompt are both written to `STDOUT`, so they are always put into the same location. When you use your redirection, it just takes the whole `STDOUT`, including the prompt.

If rewriting (as suggested in another answer by Jarmund) of the command is not possible, maybe the command has an additional option/flag (like `--output`), that can specify some output file instead of using the redirection?